# Appropriate inline try catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch

In Javascript (or for the most part, ECMAscript in general), which is the most appropriate way to write this?

```
try { ajax.abort() } catch(e) { console.error (e) }
```

## or

```
try { ajax.abort(); } catch(e) { console.error (e); }
```

It seems like semi-colons are unneeded for this situation but at the same time I normally write this on 5 lines instead of one in which case I used semicolons for their standard programmatic purpose (eol).

Both work, and I'm sure both will validate, so which is semantically correct?

Comment: They're *semantically* identical.

Comment: Read the [official specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're semantically identical, and they're both syntactically correct, because of [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9).

---

This part is opinion:

I recommend *always* writing the necessary semicolons explicitly and never relying on ASI. But even if you do that, ASI can bite you. The classic example is:

```
function foo() {
    return
        "testing";
}
```

If you call `foo`, the return value will be `undefined`, not `"testing"`, because ASI kicks in and adds a `;` after the `return`. Ouch.

Comment: Ah, I like where your head is at T.J. I really wanted a more decisive answer so I checked how a more strict language would treat this situation. My findings are synonymous with yours: http://codepad.org/XcWfViO4

Answer (score 9):

Here's an inline try-catch for **expressions**. You can compute a value in one go, but still catch exceptions and fall back to a default value when evaluation fails - similar in spirit to the ternary `?:` operator:

```
function trycatch(func, fail) {
    try { return func() }
    catch(e) { return fail }
}
```

The expression must be wrapped up in a function, so it gets executed inside `trycatch()` not outside of it. Example use:

```
let value = trycatch(() => JSON.parse("parsing fails on this input"), null)
```

Comment: `value = (() => {try{ return JSON.parse("parsing fails on this input") } catch (e) { return null } })()`

Comment: Topicstarter asked about inline usage.

Comment: This might not be 100% inline but this is a must-have utility. In fact, I personally thought I needed it inline but looking at this solution, this is way better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following function. I added [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) to document the usage and included an example.

```js
/**
 * Wraps a callback in a try-catch and returns a default value upon failure
 * @param {Function} fn - callback wrapped in a try-catch block
 * @param {Any|Function} defaultValue - value or callback
 * @param {Boolean} [silent=true] - if false, log the error
 * @return {Any} the result of either fn (success) or defaultValue (failure)
 */
const ifError = (fn, defaultValue, silent = true) => {
  try {
    return fn();
  } catch (e) {
    if (!silent) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  return defaultValue instanceof Function
    ? defaultValue()
    : defaultValue;
}

const throwError = () => { throw new Error('oops'); }

console.log(ifError(() => JSON.parse('{}', null)));   // {}
console.log(ifError(() => JSON.parse('foo'), null));  // null
console.log(ifError(throwError, () => 'Hello!'));     // Hello!
console.log(ifError(throwError, 1, false));           // (log Error) 1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```